# Pluckeye is a self-control tool. Some of its features are only accessible from a console. How do I use the console version of Pluckeye?

Tags: command-line, internet, web-filtering

[Pluckeye](https://www.reddit.com/r/pluckeye/comments/63opky/an_introduction_to_pluckeye/) is a self-control tool. It's sort of similar to Cold Turkey. It can help you prevent yourself from visiting certain websites; you choose which ones.

Much of Pluckeye's configuration can be done by pointing and clicking. But some of its features can only be accessed using the command line. The command line can be confusing. How can you enter Pluckeye command-line commands?

---

(Disclaimer: I'm one of the moderators of the Pluckeye sub-Reddit; this is a discussion forum hosted at reddit.com.)

Answer (score 0):

Pluckeye commands always start with the word `pluck`.

Let's say you want to enter the following command: `pluck add "Sometimes 12-13 Whiteout"`

Here's how.

## On Windows

- Open a command prompt. You may read [instructions](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-command-prompt-2618089) on how to do so.
- I will now tell you to enter some commands. *Entering* a command means that you must press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key after it.
- Enter the command: `cd \program files\pluckeye\bin`. If it worked, you should see: `C:\Program Files\Pluckeye\bin>`
- Enter the command: `pluck add "Sometimes 12-13 Whiteout"`. If it worked, you'll see nothing new except for: `C:\Program Files\Pluckeye\bin>`
- Enter the command: `pluck export | more`. To type the `|` vertical-bar symbol on a US English keyboard, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>. This command will show you your full set of rules. If you wish, you can verify that the rule was successfully added. If you see a `-- More --` prompt, press the space bar.
- If you'd like to close the command prompt, enter the command: `exit`.

## On Mac OS or Linux

Email me (`tealhill` at `gmail.com`) and ask me to enhance this answer to cover your operating system.

Until I see your email, try looking [here](http://www.pluckeye.net/how-to-open-a-console-window.html) and [here](http://www.pluckeye.net/notation.html).

## Notes

- Even when the Pluckeye documentation shows a dollar sign, you should never actually type it in. It represents something that you might see, not something that you're supposed to enter. The dollar sign represents a shell prompt. [(Source.)](http://www.pluckeye.net/notation.html)
- Pluckeye follows various longstanding Unix traditions. Therefore, if a `pluck` command succeeds, it often emits little or no output.